# gcc no longer works after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, gcc

As an example:

```
hsmyers@ubuntu:~/c_dev$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
printf("Hello World!\n");
return 0;
}
hsmyers@ubuntu:~/c_dev$ gcc -c -o hello.o hello.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
             from hello.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

At a guess somewhere along the way after trying to fix the error message:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory

I've munged things up completely. Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Do you already have libc-dev installed? It compiles fine for me.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install `gcc-multilib` package that brings 32bit specific headers to your 64bit operation system.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, on a fresh oneiric install. `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/predefs.h` is provided by the libc6-dev package, perhaps that is not installed correctly?

You can "reinstall" that package with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev
```

However, if that file is present, then it looks like your compiler's search path isn't looking in the right place for that file. You can check by running the following:

```
gcc --verbose -o hello hello.c
```

which should print the search path for include files. Mine says:

```
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
     /usr/include
```

If that's not the same, I'd say there is a version mismatch between some of your build-essential packages. Check that you have the right versions of the gcc, and libc6-dev packages. Right now on oneiric, these should be:

```
gcc           4:4.6.1-2ubuntu5
libc6-dev     2.13-20ubuntu5
```

Comment: result of the --verbose attempt are:

Comment: How do I reply to an answer? Minimally, my version of GCC is 4.7.0 listed as experimental. I've no idea how it got installed. In so far as I can tell, libc6-dev is installed. My include paths are similar to: /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/include (also /include-fixed) with the standard /usr/local/include as well. I can not find either bits as a directory or bits/predefs.h within it. I will try the reinstall and see what happens.

Comment: Reinstall made no difference. Found bits at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits, not shown as part of GCC include paths. My version of libc6-dev matches yours.

Comment: I'd suggest that the experimental (and non-Ubuntu-standard) version of gcc is your problem. I'd suggest removing that and installing 4.6.1 from the archive.

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking---excepting the small problem of not knowing a) how it got there and b) how to remove it. Will an apt-get remove gcc work? Or will I need the complete package name? Perhaps i686-pc-linux-gnu-4.7.0 ?

Comment: The missing `crti.o` message is caused by trying to use a non-multiarch-aware compiler with a multiarch distro (as Ubuntu now is). I'd imagine you got the new compiler from a PPA, although those normally get removed during the upgrade process. Check your software sources - if that's not it, check your path (`type gcc`) - maybe you have a gcc-4.7 snapshot install in /usr/local?

Comment: type gcc shows /usr/local/bin/gcc I'm still un-sure of how to go about getting a clean install of 4.6.1 although If I knew how to get rid of 4.7.0 I'd be a largish step in the right direction...

Comment: You can check which package that file belongs to with `dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/gcc`. Just `apt-get remove` that package.

Comment: If I do: dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/gcc I get: hsmyers@ubuntu:~/c_dev$ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/gcc
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/gcc. If I switch to /usr/local/bin and do: dpkg -S gcc the result is 209 lines of text without a single reference to 4.7---all 4.5 and 4.6. Color me still confused. Thanks for the ongoing help on this shipwreck by the way...

Comment: Don't know if this is progress or not, but am back to "cannot find crt1.o" with no mention of missing includes. Running dpkg -l *gcc* says that everything is 'un' excepting some non removable items like gcc-4.6-base. Even with all apparent gccs removed, gcc --version still reports 4.7.0 and I've no idea of where it resides.

Comment: My 4.7 is indeed located in /usr/local/bin and while I have numerous crt1.o-s, I'm fairly sure none of them are compatible with 4.7. Suggestions? (Kudos to ams for accuracy!)

Comment: So I'd suggest removing 4.7. Since it doesn't belong to a package, you must have installed it through other means. If there's nothing else important under `/usr/local`, you could just remove `/usr/local/*`, but check carefully first.

Comment: Looks as though that might be a problem---there are 7685 files in that particular tree and only a portion are 4.7 related. I think I'll try and remove the binaries and then install 4.6, cross my fingers and see what happens.

Comment: While there is still some clean up I can do, the binaries for 4.7 are now history. I've done a minimal install of 4.6 using apt-get and every thing now seems to work. The only hangup I noticed was that I was expecting gcc --version to work, but the install made no provision for the shorthand name. gcc-4.6 --version worked fine and a simple alias adds gcc easily. So to everyone who helped; Jeremy Kerr and ams much thanks! Couldn't have made it without you. Learned a great deal. BTW Jeremy are you any relation to the Kerr family out of Texas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my avr-gcc compiler.

I linked the files and folders in /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/ to a folder in which avr-gcc
searches for -files. For Example: /usr/lib/avr/include/

```
ln -s /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/* /usr/lib/avr/include/
```

Maybe something similar works for gcc. To